# Como medir los fps

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función Render que se repite infinitamente gracias a la función RequestAnimationFrame necesito una manera de medir los fps para comprobar las estabilidad de mi juego

```js
function Render(){
  window.requestAnimationFrame(Render)
}
```

Comment: Puedes medir el periodo entre cuadros (el tiempo). Teniendo el periodo, la frecuencia se calcula como `1 / periodo`.

Answer (score 0):

requestAnimationFrame recibe una timestamp como argumento, que son los milisegundo transcurridos

Un FPS es 1/T, con T en segundos, o 1000/T con T en milisegundos

Yo tenía un ejemplo de una bola rebotando, lo adecué para mostrar cómo se puede  medir los FPS. En el código deje enmarcado una pequeña porción que es lo que tu buscas

```js
const sizeSVG = document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
let FPS=50;
//Esto no es relevante
window.onload = () =>{
       bola1.incX = GetRandomVelocidad();  
       bola1.incY = GetRandomVelocidad();
       bola1.dirX = 1; 
       bola1.dirY = 1;
       bola1.radio = Number(bola1.getAttribute("r"));
       bola1.posXActual= Number(bola1.getAttribute("cx"));
       bola1.posYActual= Number(bola1.getAttribute("cy"));
       window.requestAnimationFrame(animar);
}

function GetRandomVelocidad(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

// Esto es lo que te interesa------------
let lastTimestamp = 0;
function animar(timestamp) {

    FPS = 1000 / (timestamp - lastTimestamp);
    lastTimestamp = timestamp;
    FPS_DIV.innerText= FPS.toFixed(0);
    //console.log(FPS);
//hasta aqui-----------------------------



    bola1.posXActual += bola1.dirX * bola1.incX / FPS;
    bola1.posYActual += bola1.dirY *  bola1.incY / FPS;
    
    if ((bola1.posXActual-bola1.radio)<=0 || (bola1.posXActual+bola1.radio)>=sizeSVG.width)
    {
      bola1.dirX*=-1;
    }
    if ((bola1.posYActual-bola1.radio)<=0 || (bola1.posYActual+bola1.radio)>=sizeSVG.height)
    {
      bola1.dirY*=-1;
    }
    
    bola1.setAttribute("cx",bola1.posXActual);
    bola1.setAttribute("cy",bola1.posYActual);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(animar);
}
```

```html
FPS:
<span id="FPS_DIV"></span>
<svg width="100%" height="100vh">
  <circle id="bola1"  cx="80" cy="20" r="20" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow"/>
</svg>
```

Nota: El máximo FPS de requestAnimationFrame, según la documentación es de 60